# Url not found error while using Permalink in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I was implementing a website and while doing so I am getting an error.

Actually I was trying to change a link as a `page name` , that is instead of id I am displaying name of the link.This is implemented by Permalink.

But while doing so I am getting `Url Not Found` error.

When I change Permalink back to `id (default)` from name it is displaying the same page.

Actually I want to implement this with `Permalink` in `Page Name` format.

So can anyone suggest any plugin or any help which will help me implement this ?

Comment: Have you used custom permalink ? If yes than post the permalink you have used.

Comment: @Rikesh localhost/wordpress/?page_id=123

Comment: Are you getting an error relating to mod_rewrite in the permalinks setting panel? Could be a missing .htaccess:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks

Comment: @BIOS I wiil try this and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just Try With The Following :**

In you wordpress admin, Goto **Settings** section --> **Permalinks** menu --> Choose Common Settings Option : ***Post Name***  and click save changes.

Then Goto your root directory ftp or via cpanel filemanager just check, whether **.htaccess** file existing or not, If not exist, just create one file with the name of **.htaccess** and upload it in your root directory via ftp ot cpanel filemanager.

***.htaccess file with the following content :***

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.